# Webkit browsers not fully rendering background-image

Tags: css, webkit, background-image

I've got a simple webpage with a centered background image around the main div. The background image renders fine in IE and Firefox, but on Webkit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari), the background image only partially renders when the page is initially loaded. It's almost as if the browser just quits trying to render it. If I resize the browser window, or click on any of the links on the page, the background image shows fully. Here's the site: http://www.jnrtunes.com.

I've tried various CSS hacks, preloading images, etc and nothing seems to fix the problem. Has anyone had similar issues? Is there a problem with my HTML or CSS? I'm a realtive noob to HTML/CSS, so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: hmm, interesting. it flickers a lot when I scroll in FF 3.5, I'll take a look and see if I can find anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, it's the overflow: auto on the #wrapper div that does it. Don't ask me why, but there seems to be your problem.